# How do I get the size of an attachment file?

Tags: templates, attachments

I'm using the following template code to display attachment links:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $main_post_id
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);

foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
{
    the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
}
```

but after the link I need to display the file's size. How can I do this?

I'm guessing I could determine the file's path (via `wp_upload_dir()` and a `substr()` of `wp_get_attachment_url()`) and call `filesize()` but that seems messy, and I'm just wondering if there's a method built into WordPress.

Comment: Interestingly, there is no functionality in the backend to display the size of a file wether in details nor in the list. [Ticket #8739](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8739)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As far as I know, WordPress has nothing built in for this, I would just do:

`filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment->ID ) );`

Comment: Ah - that looks much better than messing around with `wp_upload_dir()` etc.!

Comment: i need to get only one post attachment's file size. i used get_the_ID() in post_parent. but no use.

Comment: This is good, but be warned that `filesize` will throw a warning if `get_attached_file` returns false. You should add a check to ensure that `get_attached_file` returns a file that exists.

Answer (score 13):

**I would do :**

```
$attachment_filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment_id ) );
```

Or with readable size like `423.82 KB`

```
$attachment_filesize = size_format( filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment_id ) ), 2 );
```

**Refs :**
[get_attached_file()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file), 
[filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php),
[size_format()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/size_format)

**Note :** Define your `$attachment_id`

Answer (score 10):

I have used this before in functions.php to display the file size in an easily readable format:

```
function getSize($file){
$bytes = filesize($file);
$s = array('b', 'Kb', 'Mb', 'Gb');
$e = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));
return sprintf('%.2f '.$s[$e], ($bytes/pow(1024, floor($e))));}
```

And then in my template:

```
echo getSize('insert reference to file here');
```

Comment: There is no need to create a new function. WP has two of them built into core. `size_format()` and `wp_convert_bytes_to_hr()`

Comment: Looks like wp_convert_bytes_to_hr() [has now been deprecated](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19067) in favour of size_format()

Answer (score 6):

There's an easier solution, to get human readable file sizes.

```
$attachment_id  = $attachment->ID;
$attachment_meta = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($attachment_id);

echo $attachment_meta['filesizeHumanReadable'];
```

Comment: theres a wp_ funktion for everything ;-)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

To find the size of a file added through the custom fields plugin, I did this:

```
$fileObject = get_field( 'file ');
$fileSize   = size_format( filesize( get_attached_file( $fileObject['id'] ) ) );
```

Just make sure you set the custom field's "Return Value" to "File Object".

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same and found this WordPress built-in solution.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $main_post_id
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);

foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
{
    $attachment_id = $attachment->ID;
    $image_metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );
    the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
    echo the_attachment_link['width'];
    echo the_attachment_link['height'];
}
```

See more at [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

Comment: The question is about size of file as in number of bytes, not as in image dimensions.

Comment: Doh, I miss read that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For audio at least, the file size is saved as "metadata".

```
$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );
echo $metadata['filesize'];
```

This **may not** be the case for images and video.

Answer (score 1):

Get image file size in wordpress:

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query($query_images_args);

foreach ($query_images->posts as $image) {
    $img_atts = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $default);
    $img = get_headers($img_atts[0], 1);
    $size = $img["Content-Length"]/1024;
    echo round($size);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to wpse! How is this approach better then the accepted answer? Consider adding more explanation about how/why this approach is better or how it solves OPs problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems far superior, i.e. using get_headers vs. the php filesize function.  This get_headers route does not throw the 'stat failed' error if the file size is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple function to get attachment file size by attachment id, similar to another answer here but with a little error checking. There is also an additional parameter to specify the number of decimal points to return:

```
function tm_get_attachment_size($attachment_id, $decimals) {
    $file = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
    return $file ? size_format( filesize($file), $decimals ) : 0;
}
```

For example, say I have an attachment ID of 99: `tm_get_attachment_size(99, 1)` would return '1.4 MB'.