# Get file size from ACF repeater field

Tags: custom-field

I am using ACF plugin and trying to get file size which in a repeater field, but it returns nothing. Here is my code.

```
<?php if(have_rows('download')) : ?>
  <ul class="file">
     <?php
       while(have_rows('download')) : the_row();
     ?>
     <li class="custom-ul-class col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span class="file-size">
        <?php
            $attachment_id = get_sub_field('file');
            $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
            $title = get_the_title( $attachment_id );
            $filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment_id ) );
            $filesize = size_format($filesize, 2);
            echo $filesize;
         ?>
         </span>
       </li>
       <?php endwhile; ?>
     </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the size of an attachment file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/477/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-an-attachment-file)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, WordPress has nothing built in for this, I would just do. Same thing did you also. So make sure that the `$attachment_id` having value.

You can use custom function by place that function code in your `function.php` file.

```
function getSize($file){
    $bytes = filesize($file);
    $s = array('b', 'Kb', 'Mb', 'Gb');
    $e = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));
    return sprintf('%.2f '.$s[$e], ($bytes/pow(1024, floor($e))));
}
```

After place above function code, you can use `getSize($url);` where ever you use into your template. Here `$url` is reference of your file path.

Let me know if this stuff not help you.

Comment: It doesn't work. But it returns me "stat failed" error message

Comment: Please check `$attachment_id` should have ID value. If not then please check with `$attachment_id = get_field('download');`. 

Other then this your code is correct and it should work.

Comment: if you pass in the ACF file filesize, make sure you set return format of the acf field to file array, & pass the `$attachment_id[’filesize']` to this function